# Lottery: Powerball but with repeats

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, lotteries

Choose five numbers from 1-65 and a powerball from 1-25 repeats allowed. For example

> 1 1 1 1 1 24.

$65^5*25$ or ${65} \choose {5}$ $\cdot 25$?

I think the binomial coefficient is wrong because it would mean we can't use a number like 65 again and again.

Comment: You are right. Most real lotteries do not allow repeats, hence the binomial coefficient would be correct for those.

Comment: Can the five non-powerball numbers include repeats? If not, then the binomial coefficient makes sense (not "wrong")

Comment: "*choose five...* **repeats allowed**" If you really are allowing repeats among the first five numbers, then it would be $65^5$ here, but you should be warned that this is not how any lottery I've seen is run, and certainly not any of the more well known powerball lotteries like you will find in the United States.